# Stack API for generic values

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to create a stack library from scratch. It stores generic elements which are passed in `void*` pointers.

This is the defined structure:

```
typedef struct stackObject
{
    void* obj;
    struct stackObject *next;
} StackObject_t;

typedef struct stackMeta
{
    StackObject_t *stack;
    size_t objsize;
    int numelem;
} StackMeta_t;
```

So far I have implemented the following:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Creates a stack of c objects of size objsize and returns
 * a handle (pointer) to the just created stack. On error, 
 * NULL is returned.*/
StackMeta_t *mystack_create(size_t objsize)
{
    StackMeta_t *newstack = malloc(sizeof(StackMeta_t));
    if(newstack != NULL && objsize > 0){
        newstack->stack = NULL;
        newstack->objsize = objsize;
        newstack->numelem = 0;
        return newstack;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

/* Pushes an object to the stack identified by its handle
 * returns 0 on success and -1 on an error*/
int mystack_push(StackMeta_t *stack, void* obj)
{
    /* pointer to new object */
    StackObject_t *newObj = malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
    newObj->obj = malloc(stack->objsize);
    
    if(newObj != NULL){
        newObj->obj = memcpy(newObj->obj, obj, stack->objsize);
        newObj->next = stack->stack; 
        stack->stack = newObj;
        stack->numelem++;
        return 0;
    }
    else{ /* no space available */
        return-1;
    }
}

/* Pops an object from the stack identified by its handle
 * returns 0 on success and -1 on an error*/
int mystack_pop(StackMeta_t *stack, void* obj)
{
    StackObject_t *tempObj = stack->stack;
    if(tempObj != NULL){
        obj = memcpy(obj, tempObj->obj, stack->objsize);
        stack->stack = tempObj->next;
        stack->numelem--;
        free(tempObj->obj);
        free(tempObj);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

/* Destroys and cleans the stack handle */
void mystack_destroy(StackMeta_t *stack)
{
    StackObject_t *tempObj = stack->stack;
    StackObject_t *nextObj = NULL; 
    while(tempObj != NULL){
        nextObj = tempObj->next;
        free(tempObj->obj);
        free(tempObj);
        tempObj = nextObj;
    }
    stack = NULL;
}

/* Returns number of elements of the stack or -1 if invalid handle*/
int mystack_nofelem(StackMeta_t *stack)
{
    if(stack != NULL){
        return stack->numelem;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `objsize` parameter? It seems to be unused, as you only store pointers to the objects.

Comment: I can't help but point out that C++ has container types as part of its standard library, and language support for generic code.

Answer (score 1):

## Data structure

We've implemented a stack using a linked list.  That will work, but is likely less efficient than using a growable array.

We only store pointers to the objects in the stack, meaning that we are dependent on the owners of those objects for lifecycle.  If any of the objects is freed while we hold a pointer, we don't know that the pointer is no longer valid.

It might make sense to copy the passed objects to our stack instead (and if we did that, we would actually need the `objsize` member, to allocate sufficient storage).

Why is `numelem` a (signed) `int`?  I think `size_t` is more appropriate for a count of objects.

## Code

The following headers are included but not needed:

> ```
> #include <stddef.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdbool.h>
> #include <string.h>
> ```

`malloc()` and related functions work with `void*`, so there's no need to cast when assigning to other pointer types.  It's also good practice to use an expression rather than a type as argument to `sizeof` operator:

```
    StackMeta_t *newstack = malloc(sizeof *newstack);
```

If we pass a zero size, we allocate `newstack` but then leak it.  I would test for that before the allocation:

```
StackMeta_t *mystack_create(size_t objsize)
{
    if (objsize == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    StackMeta_t *newstack = malloc(sizeof *newstack);
    if (newstack) {
        newstack->objsize = objsize;
        newstack->numelem = 0;
        newstack->stack->next = NULL;
    }
    return newstack;
}
```

However, think about whether we really need the stack structure to be in allocated memory.  Is there really a good reason we shouldn't be able to use automatic storage?  It might be better to provide

```
bool mystack_init(StackMeta_t&, size_t)
```

We can still provide `mystack_create()`, but now implemented by using the init function on our allocated object.

Why does `mystack_push()` return `int`?  We had an include of `<stdbool.h>` that we didn't use, and that would be a good choice of return type to indicate success or failure.

`mystack_pop()` looks like it might be better to return a pointer, with `NULL` indicating failure.

`mystack_nofelem()` can take its argument as pointer-to-const.

Comment: I have to emphasize the remark that linked lists are **slow** on modern architectures.  Memory access time dominates, and jumping around gives you a cold cache.  Allocating and freeing when pushing and popping will be slow.  There are hour-long talks given at conferences and papers published showing that memory locality is king, and a std::vector beats a linked list even at things they teach you that linked lists are good for, for a _surprisingly large_ list size.

Comment: For very large stacks, a hybrid solution works well - a linked list of contiguous blocks of items, so we don't get problems when we `realloc()`.  But don't do that until it's necessary, as it adds a lot of bookkeeping complexity (and if/when you do, then unit-test it half to death!).

Comment: yes, that would be how `std::deque` works.

Answer (score 1):

**`objsize ==  0`**

Why error?  Code is (should be) certainly capable of handling `objsize ==  0`.

As is, code leaks memory when `objsize == 0` as `mystack_create()` allocation is lost.

**Allocate to the size of the referenced type**

Its easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// newstack = malloc(sizeof(StackMeta_t));
newstack = malloc(sizeof *newstack);
```

**Missing `StackMeta.h`**

I'd expect a companion `StackMeta.h` with the public functions.  Put the documentation there.   Users do not need to see the implementation nor the details of `StackMeta_t`.

**Info hiding**

Consider adding access functions instead of exposing `struct` members to the public.

**Use `const` as able**

This allows greater application as `const` data may pushed.

```
// int mystack_push(StackMeta_t *stack, void* obj)
int mystack_push(StackMeta_t *stack, const void* obj)
```

**Tolerate `mystack_destroy(NULL)`**

Like `free(NULL)` is OK, test the pointer.  This simplifies calling code usage, especially in error handling.

```
void mystack_destroy(StackMeta_t *stack) {
  if (stack) {
    StackObject_t *tempObj = stack->stack;
    ...
```

**Pedantic: Pushing too much is OK?**

No detection of impending `stack->numelem++` overflow.

**Why clear *sometimes***

`stack = NULL;` at the end of `mystack_destroy()` has merit, so does clearing data before free'ing it - which is not done.

**Consider a `peek()`**

Code some way to get the top without popping.

```
int mystack_peek(const StackMeta_t *stack, void* obj);
```

**Consider an `apply()`**

Code some way to apply a function to each member of the stack. Very useful.

```
int mystack_apply(const StackMeta_t *stack, int foo(void *state, void *obj), void *state) {
  // For each member of the stack, call foo(state, obj)
  // If return value is non-zero, quit loop early with that value.
```

**Reduce error**

Now, `mystack_nofelem(NULL)` returns -1 (an error).  I'd consider such benign function calls on `NULL` as OK and just return 0 here.

I doubt calling code is going to check for -1.

**Advanced: Research `restrict`**

Selectively use `restrict` on pointers for greater optimization potential.

Example: The compiler can assume `stack` and `obj` do not point to overlapping data.  (And you are letting the caller know not to attempt such pathological code.)

```
// int mystack_pop(StackMeta_t *stack, void* obj)
int mystack_pop(StackMeta_t * restrict stack, void* restrict obj)
```